How to validate a Date column given a date pattern without throwing an exception or modifying Spark Config in Apache Spark 3.0? (Java)
I have a column C1 in a data set dataset and I want to filter it so I can get only the rows that satisfies the date pattern "dd-MM-yyyy", something like:
Dataset<Row> newDs = dataset.filter(functions.to_date(dataset.col("C1"),"dd-MM-yyyy").isNotNull());

But for some input it does it right, but for others, it throws SparkUpgradeException and suggests to change some Spark Configuration to Legacy.
For some wrong input formats, like:



C1




20032024


20/12/2024


15--202



It works just fine using the previous code and it filters the dataset, but with rows like:



C1




5-9-2024


20/2/2024



It throws SparkUpgradeException. I get the following stack trace:
org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading to Spark >= 3.0: Fail to parse '5-9-2024' in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParsePolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string

What could be a good work around for doing this validation following best practices and good performance? I'm not allowed to modify the Spark config like other solutions suggest with spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY

You can try to modify the pattern used for parsing… I don't know how the implementation looks, but there's a small chance that the pattern you use ("dd-MM-yyyy") is actually expecting two digits for day of month and month of year, so that dates like the one mentioned in the error message ("5-9-2024") are considered invalid. The same date represented with leading zeros ("05-09-2024") would be parsed, I guess. Possibly, the pattern "d-M-yyyy" can actually parse such a date String.

Suggestion by @deHaar is right and working, Example code in scala.
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Filter Specific DateFormat").getOrCreate()

val list = List(
                "20032024",
                "20/12/2024",
                "15--202",
                "12-2-2023",
                "5-9-2024"
               )

import spark.implicits._
val df = list.toDF("date")

df.withColumn("mapped_date",functions.to_date(functions.col("date"),"d-M-yyyy"))
  .filter(functions.col("mapped_date").isNotNull)
  .show(false)


//output
+---------+-----------+
|date     |mapped_date|
+---------+-----------+
|12-2-2023|2023-02-12 |
|5-9-2024 |2024-09-05 |
+---------+-----------+

